# To know things versus to be known things

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice

1. We have to **know** such things
2. We have to **be known** such things

Comment: The first sentence fits the simple sentence structure of *Subject + Verb + Direct Object*, and it is a grammatically acceptable sentence. The second sentence does not fit a sentence structure because it is formed as *Subject + Verb + Direct Object +* ***Extraneous Object***.

Answer (score 1):

The first line is correct. The second line is incorrect and doesn't make any sense. To my knowledge, **be known** is used almost exclusively in the sense that something is being made aware to people. For example, I only know the use of **be known** in the following two cases:

1) "*Let it be known* that as of this day, everybody will be getting a raise in their wages!

2) "It will *be known*."

or anything similar to those two circumstances. On the other hand, **to know** is literally the verb *know*. "I have to know" is in the present tense and just means that you must know something. You can look up the verb tense conjugations online if you need help with conjugation.